# Why can't I call a function using jquery id values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some simple js code with a class constructor, an empty array and a function that takes three parameters and creates an object.  I have an HTML file with 3 input divisions as well as a button.  Lastly I am trying to use jquery to call the newCar function passing the user inputs for 'YearInput', 'MakeInput', and 'ModelInput'.

What I believe should happen is when the Add Car button gets pushed the newCar function will run passing the user inputs into the function.

```
class Car{
  constructor( year, make, model ){
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  } //end constructor
} // end Car class

let garage = [];

function newCar(year,make,model){
  console.log( 'in newCar:', year, make, model );
  garage.push( new Car( year, make, model ) );
  return true;
} // end newCar
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<input placeholder="year" id='YearInput'/>
<input placeholder="make" id='MakeInput'/>
<input placeholder="model" id='ModelInput'/>
<button id='AddCar'>Add Car</button>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(readyNow);

function readyNow() {$('#AddCar').on('click',newCar($('#YearInput').val(),
$('MakeInput').val(),$('ModelInput').val()))

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the second argument of your [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler within a function. Otherwise, it's executed as soon as it's defined, rather than on click, which is obviously what you want:

```js
class Car {
  constructor(year, make, model) {
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  } //end constructor
} // end Car class

let garage = [];

function newCar(year, make, model) {
  console.log('in newCar:', year, make, model);
  garage.push(new Car(year, make, model));
  return true;
} // end newCar

$(document).ready(readyNow);

function readyNow() {
  $('#AddCar').on('click', function() {
    newCar($('#YearInput').val(), $('#MakeInput').val(), $('#ModelInput').val());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="year" id='YearInput' />
<input placeholder="make" id='MakeInput' />
<input placeholder="model" id='ModelInput' />
<button id='AddCar'>Add Car</button>
```

Also fixed some wrong selectors for `#MakeInput` and `#ModelInput` (the `#`s were missing).

Comment: Thanks @Jeto ! This fixed my problem, although I don't fully understand why I need to add the function tag.  Doesn't the 'click' method work by calling the function only when something is clicked?

Comment: @user8735495 The `on` method just binds "something to do" to an event. It expects a function, because a function exactly means that, "something to do" later, as opposed to a basic statement whose content is executed right away. Hope that makes some kind of sense :)